# Bootstrap 3: second Carousel in Modal not advancing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel, bootstrap-modal

Here is a demo with 2 links to 2 modal windows, each with a carousel of images.  The first carousel advances fine (both automatically and with the controls).  However, the 2nd carousel does not advance with the indicators, with the controls, or even automatically.

It seems like it might be a closing  issue but I can't seem to find it.

```css
.carousel-caption {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 300;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    width: 900px;
}
.modal-body {
    padding: 0;
}
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right, .carousel-control .icon-prev, .carousel-control .icon-next {
    font-size: 60px;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-item {
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 400px;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(254,209,54,.9);
    -webkit-transition: all ease .5s;
    -moz-transition: all ease .5s;
    transition: all ease .5s;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover .portfolio-hover-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover .portfolio-hover-content i {
    margin-top: -12px;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover .portfolio-hover-content h3,
#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover .portfolio-hover-content h4 {
    margin: 0;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-caption {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 25px;
    max-width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-caption h4 {
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: none;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-caption p {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Droid Serif","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Portfolio Grid Section -->
<section class="bg-light-gray" id="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">Photos</h2>

                    <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Click on a
                    category to scroll through more images</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                    <a class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" href="#livingroom">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover-content fa fa-plus fa-3x" style="font-style: italic"></div>
                    </div><img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/500x500"></a>

                    <div class="portfolio-caption">
                        <h4>Living Room</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                    <a class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" href="#kitchen">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover-content fa fa-plus fa-3x" style="font-style: italic"></div>
                    </div><img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/500x500"></a>

                    <div class="portfolio-caption">
                        <h4>Kitchen</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
               
             
                
           
            </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Living Room   -->
<div class="modal fade" id="livingroom" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Living Room</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x500" alt="bedroom">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
A quiet retreat from the rest of the house.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x500" alt="bedroom">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Warm and cozy, yet large enough for the whole family.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x500" alt="bedroom">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
     
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

   
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
            </div></div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->




<!-- Kitchen   -->

<div class="modal fade" id="kitchen" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Kitchen</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
                 
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x500" alt="kitchen">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
  
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x500" alt="kitchen">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x500" alt="kitchen">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x500" alt="kitchen">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
            </div></div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the same ID for both carousels, so when you open the second one the controls are still tied to the first one. [Per the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-usage), **if you're using more than one carousel on the same page they both need to have unique IDs**, and the href attributes for the left and right slide controls need to point to those IDs. Also not a bad idea to update the data-target attributes of the slide indicators to also use this ID, but it's not required from what I can tell by testing everything.

```css
.carousel-caption {
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: 300;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.carousel-inner > .item > img {
    width: 900px;
}
.modal-body {
    padding: 0;
}
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left, .carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right, .carousel-control .icon-prev, .carousel-control .icon-next {
    font-size: 60px;
}
#portfolio .portfolio-item {
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 400px;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    background: rgba(254,209,54,.9);
    -webkit-transition: all ease .5s;
    -moz-transition: all ease .5s;
    transition: all ease .5s;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover .portfolio-hover-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: -12px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover .portfolio-hover-content i {
    margin-top: -12px;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover .portfolio-hover-content h3,
#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-link .portfolio-hover .portfolio-hover-content h4 {
    margin: 0;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-caption {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 25px;
    max-width: 400px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-caption h4 {
    margin: 0;
    text-transform: none;
}

#portfolio .portfolio-item .portfolio-caption p {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Droid Serif","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- Portfolio Grid Section -->
<section class="bg-light-gray" id="portfolio">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">Photos</h2>

                    <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Click on a
                    category to scroll through more images</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                    <a class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" href="#livingroom">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover-content fa fa-plus fa-3x" style="font-style: italic"></div>
                    </div><img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/500x500"></a>

                    <div class="portfolio-caption">
                        <h4>Living Room</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
                    <a class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal" href="#kitchen">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover">
                        <div class="portfolio-hover-content fa fa-plus fa-3x" style="font-style: italic"></div>
                    </div><img alt="" class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/500x500"></a>

                    <div class="portfolio-caption">
                        <h4>Kitchen</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
               
             
                
           
            </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Living Room   -->
<div class="modal fade" id="livingroom" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Living Room</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            
<div id="carousel-livingroom" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-livingroom" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-livingroom" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-livingroom" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x500" alt="bedroom">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
A quiet retreat from the rest of the house.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x500" alt="bedroom">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        Warm and cozy, yet large enough for the whole family.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x500" alt="bedroom">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
     
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

   
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-livingroom" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-livingroom" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
            </div></div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->




<!-- Kitchen   -->

<div class="modal fade" id="kitchen" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="gridSystemModalLabel">Kitchen</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
                 
<div id="carousel-kitchen" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-kitchen" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-kitchen" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-kitchen" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-kitchen" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x500" alt="kitchen">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
  
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x500" alt="kitchen">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
       
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x500" alt="kitchen">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/900x500" alt="kitchen">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-kitchen" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-kitchen" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
            </div></div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

As you can see in the code samples and working snippet above, each carousel now has a unique ID, and the href attributes of the controls for each carousel are set to work with the ID of the carousel they're within. Both modals open and each carousel moves left and right with no problems now.